# OPTION tag - Changing the font Size in a textarea field

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me to make this script working.

I have 2 textbox  input and output, and fontsize SELECT - OPTION tag ,I want to make it work in such a way that if i select any option the fontsize in textareas to be changed in real time.

thnks

```js
function myFunction() {
{
  var inputField = document.getElementById('input');
  var outputField = document.getElementById('output');
  var x = document.getElementById("textareafontsize").value;
  document.write("txt.fontsize(3)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(5)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(8)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(10)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(12)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(14)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(15)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(18)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(20)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(24)");
  document.write("txt.fontsize(30)");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Textarea Font Size.</p>

<textarea name="input" id="input" cols="75" rows="10">Hello world</textarea> 
<textarea name="output" id="output" cols="75" rows="10">Hello world</textarea> 
<br>
<select name="textareafontsize" id="textareafontsize" title="Textarea Font Size">
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="5" >5</option>
<option value="8" >8</option>
<option value="10" >10</option>
<option value="12" >12</option>
<option value="14" >14</option>
<option value="15" >15</option>
<option value="18" >18</option>
<option value="20" >20</option>
<option value="24" >24</option>
<option value="30" >30</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by learning how to use events on form controls. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. You need to research the basics yourself

Comment: @charlietfl i tried without success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up an even handler for the `change` event of the `select` so that you can execute code to change the font at the right time.

Then, all you have to do is set the two `textarea` elements `style.fontSize` to the `value` of the `select`. But you need to remember to concatenate the unit of measurement as well (I'm assuming you want points here).

You also don't need to specify `value=Nn` in each `option`. When no `value` is specified, the `value` defaults to the content of the `option`.

**NOTES:**

- You had an extra `{` just inside your function, which is a syntax
  error.
- `document.write()` is only useful when creating entirely new
  windows/documents dynamically, which you aren't doing here so you
  don't use `document.write()`.
- `txt.fontsize(3)` implies that you have an object reference named
  `txt` set up (which you don't) and that you want to call the
  `fontsize` method of that object and pass it `3`. That last bit of
  syntax is entirely wrong.

```js
var inputField = document.getElementById('input');
var outputField = document.getElementById('output');
document.getElementById("textareafontsize").addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Elements have a "style" property, which returns an object that exposes all the CSS properties
  // as properties of that object. CSS names with a hyphen get converted to no hypen, but camelCase.
  inputField.style.fontSize = this.value + "pt";
  outputField.style.fontSize = this.value + "pt";
});
```

```css
/* These styles are not essential to make the code work. They are just for 
   presentation here at Stack Overflow. */
textarea { height:100px; width:40%; float:left; font-size:3pt; }
div { clear:both; }
```

```html
<p>Textarea Font Size.</p>

<textarea name="input" id="input" cols="75" rows="10">Hello world</textarea> 
<textarea name="output" id="output" cols="75" rows="10">Hello world</textarea> 
<div>
  <select name="textareafontsize" id="textareafontsize" title="Textarea Font Size">
    <option>3</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>30</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArbnorGrezda You're welcome. Your English was fine, but in the future, you should only tag your questions with tags that indicate what technologies you are working with.

Comment: thnks but when i remove css style and i select any of option it change  and textarea size can you help me to make this working without css to change just fontsize into box, you can check here    https://jsfiddle.net/tb5cfmky/

Comment: @ArbnorGrezda You need to set the sizes of the textareas because they will grow/shrink (as you are seeing) without being set. CSS is the correct way to solve that, as I've shown in my code.

Comment: ok scott thank you ,
if it is impossible let its stay that way,thank you.